# FastAPI image POST and resize

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, fastapi

I'm creating an app using a FastAPI that is supposed to generate resized version of uploaded images.
The upload should be done through POST/images and after calling a path /images/800x400 it should show an image with 800x400 size.
This is what I have so far:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/images/")
async def create_upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    return {"filename": file.photo.jpg}
```

(photo.jpg is an image that is in the same location as the app file)

How can I see this uploaded image? When I call http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/ I get:
{"detail":"Method Not Allowed"}

How is it possible to POST more than one image and after that making a resizing on a random one by calling /images/800x400 to see it in a version 800x400?
I was thinking about using Pillow. Is it fine in this case?

**EDIT**

I'm now a step forward but still getting an error while trying to display an image.

````
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse
import uuid

app = FastAPI()

db = []

@app.post("/images/")
async def create_upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    
    file.filename = f"{uuid.uuid4()}.jpg"
    contents = await file.read() # <-- Important!

    db.append(file)

# example of how you can save the file
    with open(file.filename, "wb") as f:
        f.write(contents)

    return {"filename": file.filename}

@app.get("/images/")
async def show_image():  
    return db[0]```

As a response I get:
{
  "filename": "70188bdc-923c-4bd3-be15-8e71966cab31.jpg",
  "content_type": "image/jpeg",
  "file": {}
}

I would like to use: return FileResponse(some_file_path)
and in the file path put the filename from above. Is it right way of thinking?
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to look into what [HTTP methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) are used for.

### POST

> The POST method is used to submit an entity **(your image)** to the specified resource, often causing a change in state or side effects on the server.

So, use POST to upload the image to your backend.

### GET

> The GET method requests a representation of the specified **(image)** resource. Requests using GET should only retrieve data.

GET is the default method when navigating to a site with a browser. So, if you want to see an image when you navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/` you need a function (with FastAPI's decorator) defined for that endpoint.

Understanding these you can define the endpoints required to achieve your goal.

### EDIT

For reference, here is a working implementation of uploading and saving an image. I used Postman to perform the actual request.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse
import uuid

app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/images/")
async def create_upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    
    file.filename = f"{uuid.uuid4()}.jpg"
    contents = await file.read() # <-- Important!

    # example of how you can save the file
    with open(file.filename, "wb") as f:
        f.write(contents)

    return {"filename": file.filename}
```

This saves the image uploaded with a random ID as the file name in the directory where the application is running. Of course, you should use a proper data store but I think it should get you in the right direction.

### References

`https://www.starlette.io/requests/#request-files`

Comment: Thanks. I Understand those concepts of HTTP methods. The thing is I have never done it before with Python and I'm struggling with syntax to get expected results..

Comment: This is what I've been able to get so far: 
`
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/images/")
async def create_upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    return {"filename": file.photo.jpg}

@app.get("/")
async def main():
    return FileResponse("/images/") `
If I call http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/ I get {"detail":"Method Not Allowed"} and if I call http://127.0.0.1:8000/ I get Internal Server Error (File at path /images/ does not exist in the terminal)

Comment: I added another edit. I think at this point you should have plenty to go forward and test some more

Comment: I added an edit. I was able to move one step forward thanks to your explanations.

Comment: At this point how you return images from the GET is going to be dependent on your data store and will require more. I suggest asking a new question once you have implemented one and tried it out.

Comment: Opened a new question. Thanks